# Can I verify an Indian phone number from a Twilio trial account?

Tags: twilio

I have a trial  twilio phone number 1XXXXXXXXXXXX:

I am able to receive a call, record, voicemail, But when tried to make an outbound call ,  i am getting the below exception.

Exception in thread "main" com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException: The source phone number provided, +1XXXXXXXXXXXX, is not yet verified for your account. You may only make calls from phone numbers that you've verified or purchased from Twilio.

Here is the code:

public class MakeCall {

```
public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "My account sid";
public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "my auth token";

public static void main(String[] args) throws TwilioRestException {

    TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
    Account mainAccount = client.getAccount();
    CallFactory callFactory = mainAccount.getCallFactory();
    Map<String, String> callParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
    callParams.put("To", "+917406097660"); // Replace with your phone number
    callParams.put("From", "571-206-3804"); // Replace with a Twilio number
    callParams.put("Url", "http://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/");
    // Make the call
    Call call = callFactory.create(callParams);
    // Print the call SID (a 32 digit hex like CA123..)
    System.out.println(call.getSid());
}
```

}

Thanks in advance,

Comment: i need your help in openbravo to solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're receiving is the following:

```
The source phone number provided, +1XXXXXXXXXXXX, is not yet verified for your account. You may only make calls from phone numbers that you've verified or purchased from Twilio.
```

You should check to make sure the `From` number is a Twilio number or a number you've verified. It looks like the `From` number you've provided, 571-206-3804, is not a Twilio number - double check that it's the right value.